# How to determine what program installed Syncrosoft License Manager?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, license-key

I have the Syncrosoft License Manager installed, and as far as I can tell, this is a dongle-based licensing scheme. I do not have any software that requires a dongle, nor do I have a key dongle.

I would like to remove this program, but am not sure if it will affect one of my installed programs.

How can I determine which software (if at all) installed this license manager?

Comment: Mod was asked to move to Super User.

Comment: I was able to find the Syncrosoft installer file in one of the software packages I once downloaded and installed. In my case it was CV-Piano.

Answer (score 1):

Hope these information will present in log file in the installation location as it would log the info about the license provided to the software

**[Win XP]**

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\eLicenser\Logs\POS_Used_eLicenser_Serialnumbers.log

**[Win Vista/Windows 7/Windows 8]**

C:\ProgramData\eLicenser\Logs\POS_Used_eLicenser_Serialnumbers.log

**[Mac OS X]**

/Library/Logs/eLicenser/POS_Used_eLicenser_Serialnumbers.log

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I do not have that file in the Logs folder in the program's installation folder (no such directory under Application Data). However, a thorough search on my whole hard drive gave me the clue I needed. Syncrosoft's installer itself was found under one of the Download folders of the CV-Piano program I once installed.